# My PPTP VPN on my home network won't let me see shared folders/other devices on my home internet

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access, remote

I set up a PPTP VPN server on my home media server (same server that hosts plex and is attached to an external that has videos on it). There are also  other devices on the network I would prefer to be able to connect to. I used [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) to set it up. Because I'm on macOS Sierra there isn't a built in PPTP connection anymore. Instead I'm using [Shimo](https://www.shimovpn.com/) and it connects to my home IP just fine (right now I'm out of town).

I'm doing all this through VNC right now, but I'd prefer to just have VPN access to the network instead of having to VNC in and screen share on my media server and do stuff. So that's what I'm hoping to accomplish. When I use Shimo to VPN in, it connects successfully and when I google my external IP on my laptop (that is what I'm using remotely) it shows that my IP is my home IP. So I know that much is working.

However, I cannot access my external hard drive which is set up as a shared drive in the house. So usually when I'm at home I can just SMB into the media server and access my D drive which is where my files are. I expected to be able to do the same over PPTP, is this wrong? I'm not sure if I'm sharing enough detail but please feel free to ask clarifying questions and I'll try to answer. I have ports 1723, 47, and 445 all open which I thought might have been the original cause but it's not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. In Shimo I did the following.

1. Double clicked on preferences.
2. Double clicked on the VPN account I wanted to change to be able to access my SMB.
3. Clicked advanced.
4. Under Network Traffic control added 192.168.0.0/24 as VPN. (Make sure send all traffic through VPN is ticked)

That did it.